# Sudden Glassfish 2.1 failure

Tags: java, glassfish

So, nothing has changed with my setup over the past week. I have recently upgraded to Lion, but I have run this application several times since I have done that.

Today, I click the "Run Main Project" arrow in NetBeans 6.8, and I get a dialog box I have never seen before...

[image: Error]

I have absolutely no idea what to do. I can find no reference to this error in Google.

Steps I have taken:

- Reviewed the logs (nothing unusual up to the point where NetBeans freaks out.
- Reverted to a backup Netbeans installation (no change in behavior)
- Attempted to change the username/login information to the administrative Glassfish panel (no change in behavior)
- Removed the .netbeans directory from my home, and restored to a known good offsite backup.

I have absolutely no idea what "8228 8228 8228" means.

One thing important to note is that **Glassfish is running** and the creds that I have supplied to NetBeans do work. I can log into the running Glassfish admin panel with them.

Any suggestions at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this here for anyone who happens to run into the same problem.

I would wager that this affects all versions of NetBeans.

I am not entirely sure what caused the original issue, but it appears that NetBeans attempted to "auto-discover" a proxy that I had installed on my system. (GlimmerBlocker, for blocking ads, among other things)

When it did this, Glimmerblocker did not report its IP address correctly (or NetBeans interpreted it incorrectly), resulting in something that looked like:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:8228
8228
8228
```

Well, needless to say, when the Java NumberFormatter got a hold of that, it didn't like it one bit.

Setting NetBeans to "No Proxy" in it's settings, and restoring from backup again (to undo all the troubleshooting damage I had done) took care of the problem.

Again, leaving this only in the hopes that it helps at least one other problem who may run into something similar.